# Looping until the error stops or 15 seconds have passed

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a loop so it tries to click on the element until it finds it and if it goes beyond a 15 second limit, put a message warning about the error.

It doesn't respect the 15 second limit and stays in an eternal loop.

```vb
tlimit = 60
tfirst = Timer
On Error Resume Next
Do While Timer - tfirst < tlimit Or Err.Description <> ""

    drive.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'p-button-label') and text() = 'Erase']").Click

    If Err.Description = "" Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Timer - tfirst > tlimit Then
        MsgBox " error" & Err.Description
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

Loop
```

I'm using `Err.Description` because if I put `Err.Number` the error of not finding it in Selenium is 0, and ends up not having a condition for the `Do`.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code, it is working. The only thing is your timer is set to 60 seconds, you can change it to 15 seconds.

```
tlimit = 15
tfirst = Timer
On Error Resume Next
Do While Timer - tfirst < tlimit Or Err.Description <> ""
    drive.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'p-button-label') and text() = 'Erase']").Click
    If Err.Description = "" Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Do
    ElseIf Timer - tfirst > tlimit Then
        MsgBox " error" & Err.Description
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: I believe `Or Err.Description <> ""` puts this into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If `drive.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'p-button-label') and text() = 'Erase']").Click` fails past the time limit then `Err.Description <> ""` is True so the time limit is ignored.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub errorHandlerTest()

Dim tlimit As Long
Dim tfirst As Double

Dim errDesc As String

tlimit = 15 '60
tfirst = Timer

Do While Timer - tfirst < tlimit

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print " Do While Timer - tfirst < " & tlimit
    Debug.Print "  Timer - tfirst: " & Timer - tfirst
    
    errDesc = ""
    Debug.Print "   errDesc........: " & errDesc
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'Drive.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'p-button-label') and text() = 'Erase']").Click
    Err.Raise 0    ' for testing
    
    Debug.Print "   Err.Description: " & Err.Description
    
    If Err.Description = "" Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    
    errDesc = Err.Description
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print "   Err.Description: " & Err.Description
    Debug.Print "   errDesc........: " & errDesc
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    
Loop

If errDesc <> "" Then
    'MsgBox " error: " & errDesc
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print " error: " & errDesc

Else
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print " success"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much I doubt I can get him to repeat this part Drive.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class ... until you get rid of the error? Is it very difficult to do this in other parts of the code as if it were a wait until Selenium loads the item? thank you very much